# ¿Cómo unir dos consultas en SQL una utilizando tabla temporal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero unir dos consultas en SQL, en una consulta estoy con una tabla temporal y en la otra no uso tablas temporales, ¿hay alguna manera para unir los dos resultados?

Consulta 1:

```
SELECT
    --NumOperador= op.NumOperador,
    TiempoLaborado = isnull((dbo.FormatoFecha(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Dateadd(mi, sum(Datediff(mi, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)), '1900-01-01'), 120))), 0)
    ,TiempoNoLaborado = isnull(dbo.FormatoFecha(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Dateadd(mi, Abs(sum(Datediff(mi, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) - Datediff(mi, @FechaDesde, Isnull(DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaHasta), Getdate()))), '1900-01-01'), 120)), 0)
FROM #tmpOperadores op
LEFT JOIN trfDespacho d ON d.numOperador = op.NumOperador
WHERE (
        op.NumOperador = @NumOperador
        OR @NumOperador = 0
        )
    AND (
        (
            isnull(D.FechaSalida, 0) = 0
            AND isnull(d.FechaLlegada, 0) = 0
            )
        OR (
            D.FechaSalida >= @FechaDesde
            AND D.FechaLlegada <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaHasta)
            )
        )
GROUP BY op.NumOperador
```

[image: Consulta 1]

Consulta 2:

```
SELECT CC.NumOperador
    ,(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno) AS Operador
    ,j.Descripcion
    ,Incidencias = isnull(COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Fecha_Ini, Fecha_Fin) + 1), 0), 0)
FROM trkOperadores O
JOIN trkJornada J ON J.cveJornada = O.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON CC.NumOperador = O.NumOperador
WHERE O.cveTipoOperador = 2
    AND (
        O.NumOperador = @NumOperador
        OR @NumOperador = 0
        )
    AND (
        (
            isnull(Fecha_Ini, 0) = 0
            AND isnull(Fecha_Fin, 0) = 0
            )
        OR Fecha_Ini >= @FechaDesde
        AND Fecha_Fin <= @FechaHasta
        )
    AND CC.Jornada_Ini >= @FechaDesde
    AND CC.Jornada_Fin <= @FechaHasta
GROUP BY CC.NumOperador
    ,(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno)
    ,j.Descripcion
    ,CC.Jornada_Ini
```

[image: Consulta 2]

Agregue dos imagenes en la consulta 1 obtengo el tiempo laborado y no laborado este tiempo quiero agregarlo en la consulta dos para tener el registro completo del operador:

En este resultado quiero agregar el Tiempo Laborado y el tiempo no laborado

Comment: Hola, para hacer el `UNION` se requiere que los nombres y tipos de dato de los campos en ambas tablas sean los mismos, de otra forma, no existe lógica de unir las dos tablas.

Comment: Por favor aclara de forma concreta, tal vez por medio de un ejemplo, cual es el resultado deseado de unir las 2 consultas.

Comment: Tal como te comentó @Flxtr, hay que hacer CONSULTA1 UNION CONSULTA2. Ambas consultas deben tener la misma cantidad de columnas y cada columna debiera tener tipos de datos compatibles.

Comment: Podrías usar una [expresión de tabla común (CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms175972.aspx), con ello unes las dos definiciones por `NumOperador`.

Answer (score 1):

Más que *unir* las consultas, en el sentido SQL de la operación *union*, lo que buscas es *unir* en el sentido de la operación *join*.

Esto es bastante sencillo si [utilizas CTE's](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-gt/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx); la idea básica es hacer el cálculo de cada una de tus *tablas* de base tal como lo haces actualmente, y luego utilizar cada una de estas como si realmente se tratara de una tabla. Es más fácil escribirlo que explicarlo, de manera general la solución sería:

```
;
with
Q1 as (
select Dato1, Dato2
  from OrigenDatos
)
Q2 as (
select Dato3, Dato4
  from OtroOrigen
)
select q1.Dato1, q1.Dato2, q2.Dato3, q2.Dato4
  from Q1
       join Q2
```

He dejado intencionalmente sin calificar el tipo de join, puesto que la idea es que la solución sea genérica. En tu caso particular, que cada consulta devuelve ya un solo registro de interés, el join sería un cross join.

No he probado este código, pero debiera funcionar con pocos ajustes:

```
with
Consulta1 as (
SELECT
    --NumOperador= op.NumOperador,
    TiempoLaborado = isnull((dbo.FormatoFecha(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Dateadd(mi, sum(Datediff(mi, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)), '1900-01-01'), 120))), 0)
    ,TiempoNoLaborado = isnull(dbo.FormatoFecha(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Dateadd(mi, Abs(sum(Datediff(mi, D.FechaSalida, D.FechaLlegada)) - Datediff(mi, @FechaDesde, Isnull(DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaHasta), Getdate()))), '1900-01-01'), 120)), 0)
FROM #tmpOperadores op
LEFT JOIN trfDespacho d ON d.numOperador = op.NumOperador
WHERE (
        op.NumOperador = @NumOperador
        OR @NumOperador = 0
        )
    AND (
        (
            isnull(D.FechaSalida, 0) = 0
            AND isnull(d.FechaLlegada, 0) = 0
            )
        OR (
            D.FechaSalida >= @FechaDesde
            AND D.FechaLlegada <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaHasta)
            )
        )
GROUP BY op.NumOperador
)
, 
Consulta2 as (
SELECT CC.NumOperador
    ,(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno) AS Operador
    ,j.Descripcion
    ,Incidencias = isnull(COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Fecha_Ini, Fecha_Fin) + 1), 0), 0)
FROM trkOperadores O
JOIN trkJornada J ON J.cveJornada = O.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON CC.NumOperador = O.NumOperador
WHERE O.cveTipoOperador = 2
    AND (
        O.NumOperador = @NumOperador
        OR @NumOperador = 0
        )
    AND (
        (
            isnull(Fecha_Ini, 0) = 0
            AND isnull(Fecha_Fin, 0) = 0
            )
        OR Fecha_Ini >= @FechaDesde
        AND Fecha_Fin <= @FechaHasta
        )
    AND CC.Jornada_Ini >= @FechaDesde
    AND CC.Jornada_Fin <= @FechaHasta
GROUP BY CC.NumOperador
    ,(Nombre + ' ' + ApPaterno + ' ' + ApMaterno)
    ,j.Descripcion
    ,CC.Jornada_Ini
 )
select c2.*, c1.*
  from Consulta1 c1
       cross join Consulta2 c2
```